# Can (Moving cursor using arrow keys in terminal) interfere with moving cursor using Trackpad?

Tags: terminal, keyboard, trackpad, software

MacBook Pro MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014. MacOS Mojave version 10.14.1. In terminal Preferences I looked under the tab Keyboard because I read that it's possible to use  Moving cursor using arrow keys in terminal. ( I do not do that or want to do that, I just wanted to take a look and see what the settings look like in there. I do see a list of keys and actions and the check box was checked to " Scroll alternate screens. I do not use arrow keys to move curser and I do not have alternate screens. Could this **interfere** in any way with using my trackpad to scroll and move the pointer around just a perfectly as I can for the 2 min while waiting for the Apple Diagnostic Test?

Aslo I know what shortcuts are but what are these called?